# Taxes For Expired Worthless Puts On Invested Positions

Tags: united-states, taxes, options

My question relates to the tax implications of purchased puts that expire worthless (no gain, but loss based on the purchase price).  These puts exist to protect invested positions.

Suppose I purchase puts on SPY at a strike price that results in a cost of $1500 to hedge an invested position for the upcoming year.  Ideally, the SPY does well and the puts expire worthless with a full loss on the $1500, but the investment position in the SPY is protected.

For tax purposes, is the $1500 considered a capital loss against any capital gains for the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a long option that expires, the cost is a capital loss .  Whether it is a long term or short term capital loss depends on the holding period.

Short options that expire are treated as short term gains, regardless of the holding period.